# Issue with one of the interview ques

Tags: java, algorithm

The question is:

We have two arrays of length 100. Initially, both contain n elements (where n<100).

`Array1` contains names.

`Array2` contains number.

The user is asked to enter a name.
The program checks if the entered name exists in `Array1`. If yes, it prints the corresponding number from `Array2`.

If no, the name will be saved at the end of `Array1` and the user is asked to enter a number which will be saved at the end of `Array2`.

I'm stuck at the "if the name is not found" part. How can I enter the new value it in the end of the array?

I've created this code so far:

```
public void askUser(String[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    System.out.println("Enter the name:");
    String namedInput = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    List<String> namesList = Arrays.asList(arr1);

    if(namesList.contains(namedInput)){
        System.out.println("Yes, the name is present. And the subsequent number is: " + arr2[namesList.indexOf(namedInput)]);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Nope, the name is not present");
        System.out.println("The name "+namedInput+" will be added in the list, please enter the corresponding number: ");
        int numInput = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        // How to save the name and number in the first available indice.
    }
    askUser(arr1, arr2);

}
```

P.S.: Please suggest if you have any other optimized way.

Answer (score 3):

So if you really need to use Array for this, just remember the current number of the name-number pairs.

Say initially you have n name-number pairs, next time when you get a new one, just do

```
    if (n < 100) {
        arr1[n] = newName;
        arr2[n] = newNumber;
        n++; 
    }
    else {
        // take care of this invalid case
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A simpler (and better) way would be to use a java [Hashtable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) (**key**: name, **value**: number).

Check if the key already exists, or insert the key-value pair otherwise.

There's some sample code which shows how to use the Hashtable in the linked documentation.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. The arbitrariness of the constraints suggests either homework or asking the wrong question ('how can I implement this solution I came up with', instead of 'what solution can I use to solve this problem')

Comment: @Confusion You are right. Even I thought of the hashtable. But it is a compulsion in the problem statement that we have to use arrays.

Comment: @user1433826: arrays have a specific length. When one's full and you need more elements, create a new (larger) one and copy over the original's elements.